# How to refine heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, imshow

I have a pandas data frame the looks like this:

```
         SPX   RYH  RSP   RCD   RYE  ...   RTM   RHS   RYT   RYU  EWRE
Date                                     ...                              
2022-02-25   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-03-04   9.0   5.0  8.0  12.0   1.0  ...   6.0   4.0  11.0   2.0   3.0 
2022-03-11   8.0  12.0  6.0  11.0   1.0  ...   3.0  13.0   9.0   2.0   4.0
2022-03-18   5.0   6.0  8.0   1.0  13.0  ...   9.0  10.0   2.0  12.0  11.0
2022-03-25   5.0  12.0  9.0  13.0   1.0  ...   2.0   4.0  10.0   3.0   7.0
```

Here is the info on it:

```
>>> a.ranks.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 52 entries, 2022-02-25 to 2023-02-17
Data columns (total 13 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   SPX     51 non-null     float64
 1   RYH     51 non-null     float64
 2   RSP     51 non-null     float64
 3   RCD     51 non-null     float64
 4   RYE     51 non-null     float64
 5   RYF     51 non-null     float64
 6   RGI     51 non-null     float64
 7   EWCO    51 non-null     float64
 8   RTM     51 non-null     float64
 9   RHS     51 non-null     float64
 10  RYT     51 non-null     float64
 11  RYU     51 non-null     float64
 12  EWRE    51 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(13)
memory usage: 5.7 KB
>>>
```

I plot a heatmap of it like so:

```
    cmap = sns.diverging_palette(133, 10, as_cmap=True)
    sns.heatmap(self.ranks, cmap=cmap, annot=True, cbar=False)
    plt.show()
```

This is the result:[image]
What I would like to have is the image flipped with symbols on the y-axis and dates on the x-axis. I have tried .imshow() and the various pivot methods to no avail.

I suspect that have two questions:
Is seaborn or imshow the right way to go about this?
How do I pivot a pandas dataframe where the index is datetime?

Comment: would this help [How to include labels in sns heatmap] (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31746/how-to-include-labels-in-sns-heatmap)

Comment: That did help @capnhud. Thnx.

Comment: yw sometimes the question asked leads in the right direction glad you indicated it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip the x and y by transposing the dataframe (`df.T`, interchanging index and columns).
As the default datetime conversion also adds the time, the dates need to be converted manually to strings. `sns.heatmap` has parameters to explicitly set or change the tick labels.
Optionally, you can drop the all-NaN rows.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first create some test data similar to the given data
rank_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(1, 15, size=(52, 13)).astype(float),
    columns=['SPX', 'RYH', 'RSP', 'RCD', 'RYE', 'RYF', 'RGI', 'EWCO', 'RTM', 'RHS', 'RYT', 'RYU', 'EWRE'],
    index=pd.date_range('2022-02-25', '2023-02-17', freq='W-FRI'))
rank_df.iloc[0, :] = np.nan

rank_df_transposed = rank_df.dropna(how='all').T
xticklabels = [t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for t in rank_df_transposed.columns]
# optionally remove repeating months
xticklabels = [t1[8:] + ('\n' + t1[:7] if t1[:7] != t0[:7] else '')
               for t0, t1 in zip([' ' * 10] + xticklabels[:-1], xticklabels)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
sns.heatmap(data=rank_df_transposed,
            xticklabels=xticklabels, yticklabels=True,
            annot=True, cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=0)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', rotation=0)
plt.tight_layout()  # fit all the labels nicely into the surrounding figure
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap interchanging x and y]

Comment: Brilliant @JohanC, I learned quite a lot from your worked example. Thanks!